# pd.to_datetime with multiple format

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get a timestamp out of multiple time-formats like:

```
df['date'] = [29.05.2023 01:00:00, 
              29.05.2023, 
              28.05.2023 23:00:00]
```

At 00:00:00 on every day the time is missing and only the date has been logged.
I need the timestamp to look like this:

```
df['date'] = [29.05.2023 01:00:00, 
              29.05.2023 00:00:00, 
              28.05.2023 23:00:00]
```

Comment: you can use coerce for it

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')

Then, you can fill missing hours, minutes and seconds with defaults

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S').fillna(df['date'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y 00:00:00'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `dayfirst=True` parameter, for final ouput `DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS` use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['29.05.2023 01:00:00', 
                           '29.05.2023', 
                           '28.05.2023 23:00:00',
                           '4.10.2023']})


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
print (df)
                  date
0  29.05.2023 01:00:00
1  29.05.2023 00:00:00
2  28.05.2023 23:00:00
3  04.10.2023 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

In many cases it will work on all familiar formats
You may try addding: , format='mixed':

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='mixed')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by casting to `datetime` with a mixed format, then setting the output format to take on your chosen form:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format='mixed').dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
    date
0   29.05.2023 01:00:00
1   29.05.2023 00:00:00
2   28.05.2023 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas *pd.to_datetime()* supports datetime inconsistencies with three options

> errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’
>
> If 'raise', then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
>
> If 'coerce', then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.
>
> If 'ignore', then invalid parsing will return the input.

**coerce** can be used in this case.

Step1: Create dataframe with all inconsistent datetime format strings

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['29.05.2023 01:00:00', '29.05.2023', '28.05.2023 23:00:00']})
```

Step2: Convert them to datetime objects

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
```

Step 3: Then, the missing parts can be filled with defaults; either 00:00:00 or some other specific time.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S').fillna(df['date'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y 00:00:00'))
```

Then, output will be consistent.

```
0    29.05.2023 01:00:00
1    29.05.2023 00:00:00
2    28.05.2023 23:00:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```